# Function that returns boolean with nested subscription

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a row of mat-chexboxes that are created with a ngFor loop.

```
   <div class="permission-one" *ngFor="let permission of permissions">
    <mat-checkbox [disabled]="(!isEdit && userIndex !== i) || (isEdit && userIndex !== i)" [checked]="isChecked(fauxUser.userId, permission)" (change)="checkboxSelected($event, permission.code)"></mat-checkbox>
  </div>
```

To see if that checkbox needs to be checked when created I am calling isChecked() which looks like this:

```
isChecked(userId: number, permission: Permission): boolean {
 this.adminService.getUserAccess(this.companyId, userId)
 .subscribe((userAccessRes: UserPermission) => {
   for (const special of userAccessRes.specialPrograms) {
    if(special.programCode === permission.code && special.userAccessId !==0) 
      {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

However because of the nesting with the subscribe I cannot figure out how to get return value of the if statement to the proper level to return it for the function.
Right now my error is "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value."
Is it possible to use the function I have for my desired functionality?
any tips/suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return a boolean value directly (your `return` statement is within the subscribe callback, not the component method itself), you need to return another `Observable` using [RxJS's `map` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) and use the [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) from your view:

**Script side**:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

isChecked(userId: number, permission: Permission): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.adminService.getUserAccess(this.companyId, userId).pipe(
    map((userAccessRes: UserPermission) => {
      // test your permission here and return true or false
    })
  );
}
```

**View side**:

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="isChecked(fauxUser.userId, permission) | async"></mat-checkbox>
```

**Note**: calling component methods within directives such as `*ngIf` is sometimes considered bad practice as it can lead to performance issues. Use computed properties whenever possible.

Comment: Awesome @Jeto, thanks for assistance and the advise on the potential performance problems. Cheers